# Restricting Access to Personal Information of User

Tags: salesforce-classic

I want to restrict my users from changing their password in the personal settings. Is there any way to hide/restrict the access to that personal information page?

Comment: They're called "personal settings" for a reason. Can you explain why you don't want them to change their password using personal settings and instead some other means?

Answer (score 1):

Generally, forcing users to not being able to change their password is a Bad Idea. Especially if you choose to force all passwords to be the same. This means that anyone could "accidentally" log in as someone else and do something while logged in as that user.

This could be a security nightmare at minimum, and possibly quite the lawsuit in more severe situations. For example, this password policy is in violation of HIPAA and PCI compliance... If you value your company's data, you should definitely allow a way for users to manage their password or security tokens.

---

Administrators can [log in as another user](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=logging_in_as_another_user.htm&type=0), so there's usually no need to know a user's password. In addition, administrators can use [delegated administration](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=admin_delegate.htm&language=en_US&type=0) to allow non-system-administrators limited capacity to log in as a set of users. This covers most of the usual cases.

However, if you really wanted to prevent your users from changing their password, you could enable [delegated authentication](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=sso_delauthentication_configuring.htm&language=en_US&type=0). Basically, when a user with this configuration logs in, their password is validated by a server you control. You can simply set policies to forbid them from changing their password on the server. Salesforce will not allow a user to set or reset their password through the UI or API.

You can also write a script if you need to forcefully set a user's password. Here's a script I wrote years ago that you can add as a Custom Link to Users (note, I do tweak it about once a year for some reason or another, which is why it looks relatively "new"):

```
{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/36.0/connection.js")}
var result, newPassword = prompt("Please enter password");
if(confirm("You're about to set a new password for user...")) {
  result = sforce.connection.setPassword("{!User.Id}", newPassword);
  alert(result? result.faultcode: "Successfully set new password for user.");
}
```

Finally, you could probably set a [Login-Flow](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Login-Flows), thereby "ignoring" whatever password they have and instead force them to use a particular password. You're free to modify the experience any way that you like.